# how to send email without password?

Tags: email

This might be naive.

But is it possible in Ubuntu to have a script send out emails without requiring passwords? (via a dummy mail server, maybe)

I was hoping to use this to allow my account to periodically send info to myself (a real email account), for example, when certain task is completed. And I don't really want to risk storing the password for a real, external email account on the hard drive.

Comment: Possibly.  My ISP allows me to send mail with the only validation being my sending IP address. ie. I can `telnet smtp.myisp.net 25` into their mail server & enter details for email then exit, which of course allowed me to script it & use it for myself.  I've even had scripts send externally (not to isp email), but I've also had these rejected (I didn't explore; it was sent externally because of a typo).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, or at least it's worked for me...

My [home] ISP allows me to send mail with the only validation being my sending IP address (that I send the email from my home & not elsewhere).

I can

`telnet smtp.myisp.net 25`

into their mail server & enter commands needed to send email (as if I was a MUA) then exit, which of course allowed me to script it & use it for myself (alert me to jobs, events etc).

I've even had scripts send externally (not to my isp's email address), but I've also had these rejected (*I didn't explore; it was sent externally because of a typo, not intentionally*).

--
*My use of `telnet` was NOT intended to be the end result; it was only to prove that it's possible. My script calls functions & does not shell out to telnet. Telnet was just to prove the idea worked before I wasted time scripting it, but YES this is a dirty hack.*

Comment: I have to -1, this is a terrible thing to do. If you want to do this, you should properly configure your mail system to use `smtp.myisp.net` as a smarthost, not hack with telnet.

Comment: My use of telnet was NOT intended to be the end result; it was only to prove that it's possible.  My script uses functions & does not shell out to `telnet`. Telnet was just to prove the idea worked before I scripted it.

Answer (score -1):

Use MSMTP.

MSMTP is a program which delivers email from a local computer to a configured mailhost (mailhub). It is not a mail server (like feature-rich mail server sendmail) and does not receive mail, expand aliases or manage a queue. One of its primary uses is for forwarding automated email (like system alerts) off your machine and to an external email address.

Upstream: https://marlam.de/msmtp/

Man Page in Ubuntu: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/msmtp.1.html

Comment: This does not address the issue of password storage, since you have to store the password to your account on the mailhub.

Comment: All modern smtp, requires an authentication, unless you build an SMTP and that authentication is canceled (crazy) or that is open on your network.

This option is the best, I think.